# Verify a file move cmp bash extra line or will not work

Tags: bash

I am running a function in bash comparing two files $SRC and $DEST, I'm verifying that the command worked. Here is my working function. However if I remove the echo " " then it returns unsuccessful even if it worked. If I keep it in, it adds an extra blank output line and is successful. I've tried the following:

```
     if [[ cmp -s "$SRC" "$DEST" >/dev/null 2>&1 ]]
```

and that returns errors. Any ideas?

```
    copysuccess()
    {
    #Variable to track command
    local COM=$1
    if  cmp -s "$SRC" "$DEST" >/dev/null 2>&1 
    echo " "
    then
        echo "$COM was successful"
    else
        echo "$COM was unsuccessful"
    fi
    }
```

Update:
Tried the following codes and now it outputs

cmp: file: is a directory.

I should have noted that this was for files AND directories. Sorry.

Also if I do a move directory where it is an overwrite, it outputs nothing.

```
          Does not work:
          cmp -s "$SRC" "$DEST"; [[ "$?" = 0 ]] && echo "$COM was successful" || echo "$COM was unsuccessful"

          Does not work:
          cmp -s "$SRC" "$DEST" && echo "$COM was successful" || echo "$COM was unsuccessful"
```

Comment: Works for me without the `echo`.

Comment: The `echo " "` is a nonsense. Since echo returns OK, the "then" clause is always executed

Comment: what is meant by `if I do a move directory where it is a rename`. Are you comparing or renaming ? Updating the answer, have a look.

Comment: Sorry The whole script is part of automating linux commands for dos users. the rename has nothing to do with it, its using the copy command with the -f option to overwrite a folder, essentially overwriting the existing file with the existing. Just using this to verify the cp command worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with Jdamian's advice and using $?

I created a global that got reset every time a major function was entered, and when I got the the copy portion

```
        cp -f $SRC $DEST
        TEST=$?
```

Was added. Then

```
            copysuccess()
            {
            #Variable to track command
            local COM=$1
            if [[ $TEST == 0 ]]
            then
            echo "$COM was successful"
            else
            echo "$COM was unsuccessful"
            fi
            }
```

was the best option, I basically wanted to verify that the command ran successfully, which I wasn't clear on, and wanted to verify the copy worked, to bad my way was asinine and didn't know about the $?

Answer (score 2):

You should check return value of the executed command instead of the current approach. This is how I would've done it  :

```
cmp -s "$SRC" "$DEST" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "success" || echo "failure"
```

Since `-s` option blocks all outputs, the rest can be removed.

Comment: @BlackSimth, I think you can suppress `; [[ "$?" = 0 ]]`

Comment: I don't get it @Jdamian

Comment: Why do you explicitly test if the code returned by `cmp` command is zero? `&&` and `||` do that: `cmp -s "$SRC" "$DEST" && echo "success" || echo failure`

Comment: cmp -s "$SRC" "$DEST"; [[ "$?" = 0 ]] && echo "$COM was successful" || echo "$COM was unsuccessful"  returns unsucessfull and outputs cmp: file: is a directory when doing directories. but the copy directory still works fine

Comment: @Wilken, Are you trying to compare a regular file to a directory?

Comment: He's getting the error since removed the `>/dev/null 2>&1` part. I thought StdErr to be silent.  Add it, and it should work fine.

Comment: updated question, the new version does not work as well, plus more details.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but ended up going another route